# What is the best way to perform error handling IF your fonts don't load in React Native?

Tags: react-native, error-handling

In my React Native app I have downloaded and included custom fonts. When the app loads for the first time (App.js is my entry point) I load the fonts using Expo-Font. App.js looks like this:

```
enableScreens();

const fetchFonts = async () => {
    return Font.loadAsync({
        "roboto": require('./assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf'),
        "roboto-bold": require('./assets/fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf'),
        "arial-rounded-bold": require('./assets/fonts/ArialRounded-Bold.ttf'),
    })
}

export default function App (){
    const [dataLoaded, setDataLoaded] = useState(false);
    const [isFirstTime, setIsFirstTime] = useState(null);

    const loadAppData = async () => {
        await fetchFonts()
        const result = await isFirstTimeRun();
        setIsFirstTime(result);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        loadAppData().then(() => {
            setDataLoaded(true);
        }).catch(e => {
            console.log("error loading data: ", e.message);
            // setDataLoaded(true);
        })
    }, [])

    if (!dataLoaded){
        return null;
    }
    return (
        <NavContainer isFirstTimeRun={isFirstTime}/>
    );
}
```

As you can see the first thing I do is load my fonts. I know since they are loaded locally, it is very unlikely that they should fail to load. So, perhaps this is a silly question, but what would be the best way of handling a situation where the font-loading throws an error and they don't load. Obviously if you look at my code that would also prevent the **isFirstTimeRun()** function from executing too but that is less of an issue and I can deal with that. However, in my StyleSheets I would be using a font all over the app that didn't load.

So what would be the best way to fallback to a different font if they failed to load? I'm looking for a strategy that isn't too verbose. For example in web development you can type fallbacks but I don't think React Native offers anything like that.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: what about using `try-catch` inside `fetchFonts`

Comment: @C.K That's not necessary. If an error is thrown the catch clause of the promise will be invoked. So I'm accomplishing this already. But if the fonts don't load for some strange reason, I still want to be able to continue with the app. However, if the fonts don't load, anywhere I reference them will throw an error. Without relying on state variable to track the font style in each component, how to I provide a fallback? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

you question is valid, generally we show splash screen when app loading its components like, building modules, fonts, assets, so below is a process expo provides to its apps..

```
import "react-native-gesture-handler";
import React from "react";
import { AppLoading } from "expo";
import { useFonts } from "expo-font";
import AppNavigator from "./src/navigator";

const App = () => {
  let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    regular: require("./assets/fonts/proxima-nova-regular.otf"),
    bold: require("./assets/fonts/proxima-nova-bold.otf"),
    semi: require("./assets/fonts/proxima-nova-semibold.otf"),
  });

  if (!fontsLoaded) return <AppLoading />;
  return <AppNavigator />;
};

export default App;
```

this way, until fonts were loaded, splash screen will be shown to end users

Comment: I am using a SplashScreen. You don't see that code because I'm not using Expo. This was created with the React-Native-CLI. So, all the splashscreen code is on the native side. Still, the question isn't how to present the app UNTIL the fonts load, but rather can my app continue if the fonts don't load for some reason?

Comment: In react-native projects/ or android native projects, we generally place fonts in android font folder, android handle that's in loading time.